# Column in one entity having another entity type.Hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate

I have two entities CfBU and CfRe. I need to retrieve the data from CfBU which has a column BU_HD_RES_ID of type CfRe.The application is using hibernate 4 to which I am completely new. Code is as below

```
**CfBU.java**

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "BU_CDE")
 private String buCde;

@Column(name = "BU_NAME")
 private String buName;

@JoinColumn(name = "BU_HD_RES_ID")
 private CfRe buHdResId;
```

Comment: I don't see a field/column called `buHd`.

Comment: Sorry, mistype the column name.I have made the changes in the question.

Answer (score 0):

What's issue ?
Suppose you got CfBU object from query

```
CfBU cfBU = ...
```

To access CfRe just call

```
cfBU.getBuHdResId();
```

This will give you CfRe  Object

Comment: I tried the above but it does not work for me.I am still stuck with the same issue.                                                                                                   `           `Hibernate: 
    select
        cfbu0_.BU_CDE as BU_CDE1_3_,
        cfbu0_.BU_HD_RES_ID as BU_HD_RE4_3_,
        cfbu0_.BU_NAME as BU_NAME2_3_,
        cfbu0_.cfRe as cfRe3_3_ 
    from
        cf_bu cfbu0_
2016-11-17 12:09:02[SqlExceptionHelper:144] WARN  - SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2016-11-17 12:09:02[SqlExceptionHelper:146] ERROR - Unknown column 'cfbu0_.cfRe' in 'field list' `

Comment: you have just added joincolumn. define relation also manytoone or one to one  eg: @ManyToOne

Comment: it is `@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "BU_HD_RES_ID") private CfRe buHdResId;`

Comment: There is no column name cfRe in your entity it should be cfbu0_.buHdResId

Comment: This is my current query `select e.buHdResId.resId,e.buCde,e.buName from CfBu e where e.buHdResId.resId= :resId` . Now I am getting the below issue `java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.test.testlabs.cf.model.CfBu`

Comment: Error is very much clear its ClassCastException you need to case object to entuty type before using it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128331/discussion-between-user1662039-and-ashish451).